# php array insert element and keep keys

Tags: php, arrays

here i've got my array(the `****` are just strings)

```
        [m_timestamp] => ****
        [n_id] => ****
        [n_name] => ****
        [n_material] => ****
        [n_neck_finish] => ****
        [n_weight] => ****
        [n_height] => ****
        [n_qty_p_ctn] => ****
        [n_ctn_dimensions] => ****
        [n_comment] => ****
        [sha1] => ****
```

how can i insert another array:

```
        [n_group] => ****
        [n_available] => ****
```

into the original one so that it looks like:

```
        [m_timestamp] => ****
        [n_id] => ****
        [n_name] => ****
        [n_group] => **** //inserted
        [n_available] => **** //inserted
        [n_material] => ****
        [n_neck_finish] => ****
        [n_weight] => ****
        [n_height] => ****
        [n_qty_p_ctn] => ****
        [n_ctn_dimensions] => ****
        [n_comment] => ****
        [sha1] => ****
```

**i know the key value of where to insert the array(in this case: `n_name`)**

What i did:

```
$pos = intval(array_search("n_name", $myarray))+1;
array_splice($myarray, $pos, 0, $insertedarray);
```

but it doesn't put the `$insertedarray` properly, it adds this `[0]=>null` in the position I specified

how can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert element into array to specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-array-to-specific-position)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function:

```
$out = array_merge($first_array, $second_array);
```

**UPDATE**

Use this to merge your arrays and preserve keys:

```
// slice $myarray into two parts and insert $insertedarray in between
// keys are preserved
$myarray = array_merge(array_slice($myarray, 0, $pos), $insertedarray, array_slice($myarray, $pos));
```

Comment: @Tom91136 why is that? you are using associative arrays

Comment: i need them to be in order because later on i used next() , previous() alot

Comment: Please vote to close question as duplicate as well, you gave the same answer as in the other question.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, it seems so

Answer (score 0):

you could use array_push http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

source: php manual(examples)

```
<?php

function array_put_to_position(&$array, $object, $position, $name = null)
{
        $count = 0;
        $return = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $v)
        {  
                // insert new object
                if ($count == $position)
                {  
                        if (!$name) $name = $count;
                        $return[$name] = $object;
                        $inserted = true;
                }  
                // insert old object
                $return[$k] = $v;
                $count++;
        }  
        if (!$name) $name = $count;
        if (!$inserted) $return[$name];
        $array = $return;
        return $array;
}
?>

Example :

<?php
$a = array(
 'a' => 'A',
 'b' => 'B',
 'c' => 'C',
);

print_r($a);
array_put_to_position($a, 'G', 2, 'g');
print_r($a);

/*
Array
(
    [a] => A
    [b] => B
    [c] => C
)
Array
(
    [a] => A
    [b] => B
    [g] => G
    [c] => C
)
*/
?>
```

Comment: i know that but how do i specify the position?

Comment: take a look on the comment what you got earlier maybe that one is the workaround what you need