# PHP i can't save value on textbox into array more than one, i am not yet how to do that

Tags: php, arrays

```css
$data = array();

$x = count($data)+1;
echo $x;
$data[$x] = $_GET['nama'];

for($i=0;$i<=count($data);$i++){
echo $data[$i];
}

?>
```

i had thinked, but not yet have solved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just push to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Kito Why don't you use array_push function to push the element at the end of the array. Just like this:

```
array_push($data, $_GET['nama']);
```

or you can simply use:

```
$data[] = $_GET['nama'];
```

Comment: oh sorry, i don't now
thanks, that is very helpful
but, only ask, is there any way to use the index method

Comment: Your welcome. If you need to put an element between other elements and in a certain index of the array please check the following link: [How to insert element into array to specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-array-to-specific-position)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$x = count($data)+1;
echo $x;
$data[$x] = "test";

for($i=1;$i<=count($data);$i++){
    echo $data[$i];
}
```