# php - insert item at any array position with key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my array:

```
array(
99 => 100,
53 => 200,
29 => 300
)
```

I would like to add a new item at index 2 like this:

```
array(
99 => 100,
53 => 200,
36 => 'new',
29 => 300
)
```

I only found a solution to add a new item without own key,
have anyone an idea?

Comment: what's so difficult about `$foo[36] = 'new'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Comment: so you want to insert to a specific index of an array? possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-array-to-specific-position

Answer (score 0):

```
$table[36] = 'new'
```

In case of duplicate entry, you should reinsert the entry with a new key before.

```
$table[] = $table[36];
$table[36] = 'new';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted and it looks like this.

You can add the new element:

```
$array[36] = 'new';
```

and sort it afterwards:

```
krsort($array);
```