# how to assign the order to array elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I've written a php code that accepts month from user and returns number of days in that month. This is the php code:

```
<?php

// function to check leap year
function is_leap_year($year) {
    return (( ($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0) ));
}

//array of month and day
$month_day = [
    'jan' => 30,
    'mar' => 30,
    'apr' => 31,
    'may' => 30,
    'jun' => 31
];

//store current year in a variable
$current_year = date('Y');

//if current year is leap year
if (is_leap_year($current_year)) {
    //then, 29 days for february
    $month_day['feb'] = 29;
} 
else {
    //else, 28 days for feb
    $month_day['feb'] = 28;
}
?>
<!-- html forn -->
<form action="">
    <select>
        <?php 
            //looping into array to create option tag
            foreach ($month_day as $month => $days) {
                echo "<option>$month</option>";
            }

        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

the output of that code is this:
picture showing output of the above code

[image: picture showing output of the above code]

but i need output like this:
picture showing the required output

[image: picture showing the required output].

how to assign second order to feb element of the `$month_day` array? If its not possible, then how to use that if condition as ternary operator inside array? I've seen some threads in this site regarding 'using if inside array' but it gives me error when i used. I appreciate if you answer with code showing just array section with ternary operator used.

Comment: To get the number of days in a month use [cal_cal_days_in_month](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_cal_cal_days_in_month.asp)

Comment: @FrayneKonok - Best to link to the [PHP Manual for cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/cal_days_in_month) instead of W3School.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [How-to-insert-element-into-arrays-at-specific-position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354804/1817690) but you can do it by placing `feb` while making array like,

```
$current_year = date('Y');
//array of month and day
$month_day = [
    'jan' => 30,
    'feb'=>is_leap_year($current_year) ? 29: 28
    'mar' => 30,
    'apr' => 31,
    'may' => 30,
    'jun' => 31
];
// now run loop here
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it in the initial array?

```
$month_day = [
    'jan' => 30,
    'feb'=> is_leap_year($current_year) ? 29 : 28,
    'mar' => 30,
    'apr' => 31,
    'may' => 30,
    'jun' => 31
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to sort an array. You easiest approach is to simply re-create the array adding all elements in the order you desire. Or you use the [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function to sort while keeping the index association intact.

However a *much* easier approach in this case is to simply create the array in the correct order right away:

```
<?php 
$month_day = [
    'jan' => 30,
    'feb' => is_leap_year(date('Y')) ? 29 : 28,
    'mar' => 30,
    'apr' => 31,
    'may' => 30,
    'jun' => 31
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
// function to check leap year
function is_leap_year($year) {
    return (( ($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0) ));
}

//array of month and day

//store current year in a variable
$current_year = date('Y');

//if current year is leap year
if (is_leap_year($current_year)) {
    //then, 29 days for february
    $month_day['feb'] = 29;
} 
else {
    //else, 28 days for feb
    $month_day['feb'] = 28;
}
$month_day = [
    'jan' => 30,
     'feb'=> $month_day['feb'],
    'mar' => 30,
    'apr' => 31,
    'may' => 30,
    'jun' => 31
];

?>
```