# Add new element in array after particular value in PHP?

Tags: php

Array as per below-

```
Array ( [1] => staff [2] => Name [3] => Email [4] => surname [5] => registrationno )
```

I want to add the new value in array after [3] = > 'Email'

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert element into arrays at specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-arrays-at-specific-position)

Comment: Use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

Comment: Please search for previous questions before posting new one's. That's what stackoverflow recommends.

Answer (score 1):

use **[array_splice():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)**

```
<?php

$array = array( 
    '1' => 'staff',
    '2' => 'Name',
    '3' => 'Email',
    '4'=> 'surname',
    '5' => 'registrationno',
);

array_splice($array, 3, 0, 'myvalue');

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_splice();

`$input = array ( [1] => staff [2] => Name [3] => Email [4] => surname [5] => registrationno );
array_splice($input, 3, 0, "myvalue");
//$input is now array ( [1] => staff [2] => Name [3] => Email [4] => myvalue [5] => surname [6] => registrationno );`