# How to push array elemnt to specific position in another array using php

Tags: php, arrays, array-push, array-splice

I want to push new array to another array at specific position  for this purpose I used array_splice followed some stackoverflow links but it didn't work for me

I refered this links also but they mentioned only for single value not array.

[How to insert element into arrays at specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-arrays-at-specific-position/3354011)

[Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

```
Example:

$array_1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$array_2 = array(a,b,c);
```

Now I want to push `$array_2` values in  `$array_1` at certain position like:

```
a at position 1

b at position 3

c at position 4
```

Expected output:

```
$final_array=(1,a,2,b,c,3,4,5);
```

Comment: It is mostly the same way as for single values, just loop the second array, then insert the values wherever you want

Comment: how do u know the position?

Comment: @TsaiKoga  array_1  is final array so I have requirement to  print  some values  by push new item specific position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `positions` as array and combine it with `array_2`. Now iterate over this combined array and use code of first reference thread:

```
<?php

$array_1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array_2 = array('a','b','c');

//define positions array
$positions = array(1,3,4);

//combine position array with $array_2
$positionArray = array_combine($positions, $array_2);

//iterate over combined array
foreach($positionArray as $key => $value){
    //use code of first example thread
    array_splice($array_1, $key, 0, $value);
    //here $key is position where you want to insert
}

print_r($array_1);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/Djar2

Comment: Singh thanks for your great effort answer is exactly as per expectation,I never thought of array_combine I was doing simply using array_splice.