# php - create new array by key condition and fill by another array value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to create new array by checking index number and fill that index by another array.

Here in loop if current element index is in index 4

it will take value from another array.

and the value on that position will move to next loop.

My current two array like this

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => 'number 1', 
    1 => 'number 2',
    2 => 'number 3',
    3 => 'number 4',
    4 => 'number 5',
) ;


$arr2 = array(
    0 => 'number 4 insert', 
    1 => 'number 8 insert',
    2 => 'number 12 insert',
    3 => 'number 16 insert',
    4 => 'number 24 insert',
) ;
```

My expected new array I want like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'number 1',
    [1] => 'number 2',
    [2] => 'number 3',
    [3] => 'number 4 insert',
    [4] => 'number 4',
    [5] => 'number 5',
    [6] => 'number 6',
    [7] => 'number 8 insert',
    [8] => 'number 7',
    [9] => 'number 8',
    [10] => 'number 9',
    [11] => 'number 12 insert',
    [12] => 'number 10',
    ...
    ...
)
```

For this solution I am trying this but it generally replacing my main array value not by pushing value on selected key index I want.

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => 'number 1', 
    1 => 'number 2',
    2 => 'number 3',
    3 => 'number 4',
    4 => 'number 5',
) ;


$arr2 = array(
    0 => 'number 4 insert', 
    1 => 'number 8 insert',
    2 => 'number 12 insert',
    3 => 'number 16 insert',
    4 => 'number 24 insert',
) ;


function match_arrayKeys ($x, $y,$z)
{
    $keys    = array_keys ($x);
    
    $keysy    = array_keys ($y);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($keys); $i++)
    {
        $j = $i+1;
        if($j%$z== 0 ){
            $newarray [$i] = $y[$i-1];
        } else {
          $newarray [$i] = $x[$i];
        }
        
    }
    return $newarray;
}

print_r (match_arrayKeys ($arr1,$arr2, 4));
```

**[FIDDLE](https://3v4l.org/spdep)**

Comment: What is the logic behind this desired order? And why do your strings say "replaced" when they need to be inserted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert element into arrays at specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-arrays-at-specific-position)

Comment: @El_Vanja ok I changed my string text.

Comment: Where is `$arr2` coming from?  Might it make this task easier to update `$arr2`'s keys to be the position in the resulting array where you want want each element?  Such as `$arr2 = [3 => 'number 4 insert', 7 => 'number 8 insert']`?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question: you have an array which has input in the format of "number i" where i is the index of the element and a number z which has an integer. Now on passing to the function, you want every zth element to say "number z replaced"? Is it so?

Comment: How are you expecting to generate the occurances that dont exist in either array? You base your loop on the size of `$keys` so the result will never be what you want

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i know that loop will be not much. So i stacked how can I create my expected array.

Comment: @freeroamer90 no 'number i' is not my case. i want key inded will  check and value from another array will push on that index. old index will move to next index

Comment: I dont know what the magic word is that you want us to use to magic up `'number 6', 'number 7', `'number 8'` .... etc etc That dont exist in either array

Comment: @LemonKazi so what is the value z? and will the 2nd array be always in the format of "number i replaced"?

Comment: @freeroamer90 value z is just the key position like number 4  if (index $i+1) % 4 ==0 means it will check every 4,8,12 ... key position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```php
function match_arrayKeys($arr1, $arr2, $gap)
{
    $index = $gap - 1;
    while ($element = array_shift($arr2)) {
        array_splice($arr1, $index, 0, $element);
        $index += $gap;
        if ($index > count($arr1)) break;
    }
    return $arr1;
}

print_r(match_arrayKeys($arr1, $arr2, 4));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it close.. I want all value from two arrays.  also just according to position 2nd array value will display.

Comment: Just remove the break condition. Then the rest of the second array will be at the end. You described the expected result is not entirely clear for the original arrays. Its dimension exceeds both of the original ones.